# Can't upload any file by File Manager after upgrade to MODX 2.6.5

Tags: modx-revolution

After last attacks, I upgraded MODX to 2.6.5 version. And now there is a problem with uploading files via Modx File Manager. There are no errors during uploading. Message in File Manager after all is "File successfully uploaded" but file isn't uploaded.
In logs there are several errors but nothing about file transfer. A lot of error in /core/xpdo/xpdo.class.php:

```
Could not load class: fastFieldParser from fastfieldparser.
Problem getting service parser, instance of class fastFieldParser, from path /core/components/fastfield/model/fastfield/
```

Where can i find solution if there are no errors about file transfer problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend re-running the upgrade. I've found that Susan's install script works very well for quick reinstallations. If that doesn't work I'd recommend reviewing the server's PHP logs to see if there's anything useful in there.

Install script: [MODX Install Script](https://github.com/sottwell/installer)